# How to edit a file in Opencart 3.x with an extension?

Tags: xml, opencart-3

```
<modification>
<code>Test</code>
<id>test</id>
<version>1.0.0 </version>
<author>testing</author>
    <file name="admin/language/*/catalog/product.php">
        <operation>
            <search position="after" error="log"><![CDATA[// Entry]]></search>
            <add><![CDATA[
            $_['entry_percentage']         = 'Discount %:';
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

I am trying to add a language key through an extension and above is the XML code. It is inside a zip file which is named as xxx.ocmod.zip and uploaded via OC uploader. XML file name is install.xml. It installs without errors but does not make any effect to the file. The extension is shown under extensions as well. What is the wrong in the code and why it is not working? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is formated for vqmod.
For ocmod should be:

```
 <modification>
<name>Test</name>
    <code>Test</code>
    <id>test</id>
    <version>1.0.0 </version>
    <author>testing</author>
        <file path="admin/language/*/catalog/product.php">
            <operation error="log">
                <search><![CDATA[// Entry]]></search>
                <add position="after"><![CDATA[
                $_['entry_percentage']         = 'Discount %:';
                ]]></add>
            </operation>
        </file>
    </modification>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. does not work. What should be the file name and .zip file format?

Comment: file name should be `install.xml`  inside  `your_esxtension.ocmod.zip`. after you install it do not forget refresh modifications.

Answer (score 0):

file name should be install.xml inside your xxx.ocmod.zip. You can install it working very well.

Your XML formate is vqmod. You should try my ocmod code is below :

```
<modification>
<code>Test</code>
<name>test</name>
<version>1.0.0 </version>
<author>testing</author>
    <file path="admin/language/*/catalog/product.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[// Entry]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
            $_['entry_percentage']         = 'Discount %:';
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

i hope above code is 100% working well